# PySpark: how to create a RDD of lists of unique strings from a given RDD (id, [strings])

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark. Suppose now I have a RDD1 whose data format is a tuple of (id, list[strs]), such as:

```
(id1, ["okay"，"okay", "not Okay"])
(id2, ["okay","good","good","good1"])
```

Now i want to create another RDD2 from this given RDD1 which only contains lists of unique strings from each sublist, such as:

```
["okay", "not Okay"]
["okay", "good","good1"]
```

Could you guys please let me know how to process this operation? I first flattered the RDD1 and called the distinct() function, but this would only gave me a full list of unique string. What I really want is to have the unique string in each list of the original RDD1.

Lastly, suppose I have a HashMap, can i make it into an RDD? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rdd1.map(lambda x: list(set(x[1])))`

Comment: @pissall Thank you so much this is amazingly straight forward! May i ask a follow up question? Like now I have this new RDD2, how can i create another RDD3 which is a HashTable<String, Integer>, it tells me how many rows contains each string in this RDD2? Thank you!

Comment: Please pose it as a different question, and I can help you with the same. Please include a reproducible example/data

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter()` for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use:

```
rdd1.map(lambda x: list(set(x[1])))
```